# sed: What does exit code 2 mean?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, sed, cmd.exe

## Case

I am trying to replace all occurrences of `<value>*</value>` into `<value>file:\\</value>` in a designated file `test.txt`.

I work on Windows and use `sed` I have installed with Win-32 compiled set of bash utils.

I use a following command:

`sed -n "s/<value>.*<\/value>/<value>file:\\\\<\/value>/g" "test.txt" > "test.txt.new"`

I want to run this command as a part of [Wpkg](http://wpkg.org) script.

## Problem

When I use this command from commandline, everything works properly.

But when I use this command via [Wpkg](http://wpkg.org) script:

```
<install cmd='%BASH%\sed -n "s/&lt;value&gt;.*&lt;\/value&gt;/&lt;value&gt;file:\\\\&lt;\/value&gt;/g;" test.txt" > "test.txt new"' />
```

...then what I get is:

```
Exit code returned non-successful value (2) on command '%BASH%\sed -n "s/<value>
.*<\/value>/<value>file:\\\\<\/value>/g;" "test.txt" > "test.txt.new"'.
```

The above means that `sed` application returned exit code 2. Additionaly, the new file has not been created.

I browsed google for a really long time and to my surprise, `sed` seems to have a pretty poor documentation. I have found no documentation regarding this exit code.

## Question

Anyone got a clue **what does exit code 2** mean for `sed`?

...or an alternative solution?

(must be unattended, pretty sure might use common bash tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that your problem is with `sed`. Is %BASH% supposed to evaluate to a directory in which the `sed` executable resides and have you confirmed that it does so? Because my expectation would be that (if defined at all on Windows) %BASH% would evaluate to the path to the `bash` executable itself, in which case appending "\sed" onto it makes no sense.

In particular I'll note that the DOS error code 2 is "File Not Found" - perhaps it's an issue with finding the file "%BASH%\sed"?

Comment: %BASH% is defined properly, but... "2" being a DOS error code, rather than sed's, is a great tip. I wonder if it might be the lack of .exe extension, that's really causing the problem :) I'll check soon, thanks!

Comment: I've encountered problems when using Posix utils (e.g. 'find') on Windows from .bat/.cmd files, because the commands output and expect *nix-style paths. You don't appear to have that in your expression, but I've never used Wpkg - is it looking for *nix style paths even on Windows?

Comment: If I were to run sed from within bash, I would have to use *nix style paths indeed. But, when run using cmd, standard Windows paths work properly.

Answer (score 3):

#### Does sed issue an exit code?

> Most versions of sed do not, but check the documentation that came
> with whichever version you are using. GNU sed issues an exit code of 0
> if the program terminated normally, 1 if there were errors in the
> script, and **2 if there were errors during script execution**.

Source [THE SED FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html):